# How to use Semi-Transparent Images In an ImageList

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap, transparency, imagelist

I have an image that contains semi-transparent Images. I am then using this to bind to a ListView.

When I add the images to the ImageList (done at Runtime) the part that is transparent is turned grey.

As an example this shows the same image being loaded directly into a PictureBox and then via an ImageList into a PictureBox

The actual image is being created in memory, but this code gives the output as stated

```
    Dim tempFilename As String = Path.GetTempFileName
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    client.DownloadFile("http://s32.postimg.org/k2fdrw3wh/Semi.png", tempFilename)
    Dim empIcon = Image.FromFile(tempFilename)

    PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White
    PictureBox1.Image = empIcon

    PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.White
    Dim imglst As New ImageList With {.ImageSize = New Size(32, 32), .ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit, .TransparentColor = Color.White}
    imglst.Images.Add(empIcon)
    PictureBox2.Image = imglst.Images(0)
```

PictureBox1 on the left 2 on the right:

[image]

How can I get the ImageList to output the image on PictureBox1?

Comment: It works well for me (using C#). Are you working on Windows? (I had similar issues on Linux before.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the transparency of the image by:

```
Dim transColor = CType(empIcon, Bitmap).GetPixel(1, 1)
```

and set it to the `ImageList`:

```
Dim imglst As New ImageList With {
    .ImageSize = New Size(32, 32),
    .ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit,
    .TransparentColor = transColor
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. Interestingly the actual color is `ARGB(150, 254, 254, 254)`, but the color I am using as an overlay is `ARGB(150, 255, 255, 255)` which I had tried